# In Laravel, what is the best way to request some data from a Model or Controller directly from the View?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have 2 tables: *Products* and *Images*.

Each Product has many Images (through product_id foreign key)

```
*product_id, product_title*
1, "Product 1"
2, "Product 2"
3, "Product 3"
4, "Product 4"
```

```
*image_id, product_id(foreign key), image_url, created_at*
25,  1,  "/filename_xyz", '5:00'
26,  1,  "/filename_abc", '5:30'
27,  2,  "/filename_def", '6:30'
28,  1,  "/filename_abc", '7:00'
29,  3,  "/filename_def", '8:00'
```

I have a controller that returns all the products into my view.

*ProductController.php*

```
public function index(){
        $data_to_return = Product::orderby('product_id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

        return view('product.index', [
            'product_data' => $data_to_return,
        ]);
    }
```

This controller loads into view *product.index* correctly.

I successfully loop through the results in my blade file like this:

```
@foreach($product_data as $product)
{{ $product->product_title }}
<!--however, I would like to also print one of the images linked to a product-->
@endforeach
```

**I am having trouble planning  a "link" or "join" to an image. For Product with product_id=1, there are multiple entries in the Images database. I would like my view to bring product information from Products table as well as ONLY ONE image from Images table (matching product_id). In my case, I need the first result (or Limit 1) when ordered by created_at ASC.**

Example: Product 1 would bring into my view an image_url of "/filename_xyz" because it was the one created first from Images with product_id = 1

I was thinking that the solution could be something like this:

Loop the array of Products:

```
@foreach($product_data as $product)
{{ $product->product_title }}

<!-- And calling a controller like -->

{{Image::mainImage($product->id)}}

<!-- Where mainImage returns the image_url I am looking for-->
@endforeach
```

or

Designing my Model better, joining the tables first in a certain way that does what I mentioned before showing only the one image I am interested in. I can't figure out how to achieve this with the best Laravel/Eloquent practice.

Comment: {{ $product->image_url[0] }}

Answer (score 0):

That's where Eloquent relationships would come in handy!

Your models' relationship should resemble this setup;

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('your/path/to/image/model');
    }
}

class ProductImage extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('your/path/to/product/model');
    }
}
```

And if set up properly, you'd do something like `<img src="{{ $product->image->image_url }}">` in order to display the product image. This assumes that you only have one image per product.

In your migrations, say for instance in your `product_images` table migration, you should write `$table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();`, and Laravel will automatically know where to look for the corresponding image entry.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! How would you approach the problem when you have multiple Images linked to the same product_id but only returning the first image row found, not the rest of the images (the image would be : order by 'created_at' ASC LIMIT 1).

Comment: If you have more than one `product_image` per `product` row, then I would update the above Product relationship from `hasOne` to `hasMany`, and you could call `$product->images::first()`. I believe that's how it would work, I haven't tested this yet, mind you, but that should be the rough idea